# Group of order 30 can't be simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I have this following question from my class note on Sylow Theorem:

> Show that a group of order 30 can not be simple.

For that I know the followings:
(1) A simple group is one that does not have non-trivial normal group, 
(2) Group $G$ is *p*-group if there exists an integer $e$ such that $|G| = p^e,$ 
(3) A $p$-subgroup $H$ of $G$ is called *Sylow* *p*-subgroup of $G$ if $p \nmid |G/H|,$ and finally 
(4) A subgroup $H$ of $G$ is a Sylow *p*-subgroup if there exist integers $e$ and $m$ such that $|G| = p^em,$ and $(e, m) = 1,$ and also $|H| = p^e,$

but unfortunately I don't know how to weave them into a solution, any help would therefore be very much appreciated. Thank you for your time and help.

PS. If you have choices of elegant versus dummy down-to-earth solutions, do please give me the latter. I know it would be tedious for you but you have a slowpoke turtle down here. Thank again for your patience.

**POST SCRIPT :** ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
I came across a very simple solution by John Beachy [here](http://www.math.niu.edu/~beachy/abstract_algebra/study_guide/soln74.html#s7417), consisting of only 2 lines, which I adapted to fit group order of 30:

**EDIT (j.p.)** Unfortunately the linked solution cannot be easily adapted to this case here. I kept the text as far it was correct.

(1) Recall Sylow's Theorem: If $|G| = p^em; p, e, m \in \mathbb Z^+; (p, m) = 1;$ the number of $Syl_p (G) = s$, then $s \equiv 1\pmod p$ and $s \mid m.$ 
(2) For $|G| = 5 \cdot 2 \cdot 3$, suppose that $p = 5, e = 1$ and $m = 6.$ Therefore $s \equiv 1\pmod 5 $ and $s \mid 6,$ thus $s = \{1, 6 \}$. The 5-Sylow subgroup is normal if and only if $s=1$, and in this case $G$ is not simple.
(3) Now look at [Nirdonkey's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1077072/669).

Hope this will be useful for some of you and thank you very much for those of you who have helped me.

Comment: Sylow's Theorem

Comment: Have you learned the Sylow theorems yet? How many Sylow $p$-subgroups are there?

Comment: Nowadays being 30 is far from simple. It's something that is reflected in group theory.

Comment: Part (3) of your postscript surprises me a bit. Since when is 6 a prime number?

Comment: @j.p. :  Oops! I am glad you got my mistake.  I will make correction. Thanks.

Comment: How do you get in (2) that 5-Sylow subgroups are normal if $s=6$?

Answer (score 15):

If $G$ is a group of order 30, then the number of Sylow 5-subgroups is congruent to 1 modulo
5 and divides 30, so it must be 1 or 6. And the number of Sylow 3-subgroups is congruent to
1 modulo 3 and divides 30, so it must be 1 or 10. If there is a unique subgroup of order 3 or
5, it is normal and we are done. If not, there are 6 subgroups of order 5 and 10 subgroups of
order 3. But all of these groups must be cyclic, so every non-trivial element of such a subgroup
is a generator of the subgroup. It follows that no non-trivial element of $G$ is contained in more
than one of these subgroups. But then we have at least $6 \cdot 4 + 10 \cdot 2$ elements in $G$, which is a
contradiction.

See also [Group of order $|G|=pqr$, $p,q,r$ primes has a normal subgroup of order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/940293/group-of-order-g-pqr-p-q-r-primes-has-a-normal-subgroup-of-order?rq=1)

Comment: I like your solution since my note covers the modulo $p$. One typo though: On the second line from above, "And the number of Sylow 5-subgroups is... " Don't you think it should be "... Sylow 3-subgroups... " instead? Thanks again and again.

Answer (score 5):

By Cayley's theorem, a group $G$ of order $30$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_{30}$ is such a way that no non-identity element of $G$ has any fixed point. There is an element $t$ of order $2$ in $G$ which is represented by a product of $15$ $2$-cycles, so as an odd permutation. The elements of $G$ which are represented as even permutations of $S_{30}$ form a normal subgroup of index $2$, so $G$ is not simple.

Comment: Why can you get an embedding into $S_n$ with no fixed points?

Comment: Let $G$ act on $G$ by right translation. Only the identity fixes any point in this action.

Comment: Hmm, so this proves that there is no simple group of order $2m$, where $m>1$ is odd.

Comment: Yes, it does (this is a well known fact) In fact, it also shows that if a group $G$ whose order is of the form $2^{a}b$ (where $a$ is a positive integer, and $b$ is an odd integer) has cyclic Sylow $2$-subgroups, then $G$ is not simple ( for an element of order $2^{a}$ is represented by an odd permutation in Cayley's representation).

Comment: @Nishant: I wanted to point out to you that Thompson's transfer lemma is another possible generalization of this line of argument, but then the first hit on google was [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860332/proving-the-thompson-transfer-lemma). You get the conclusion of your comment by taking $k=1$ in your question from July (looks a bit odd, but that's probably the reason you didn't make your observation back then).

Comment: To be fair, I should point out that this was probably not the way the question was intended to be solved, since it doesn't really use Sylow.